# What are the correct token types for DI

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-di

In angular1 we had only type of tokens for providers - strings. In angular2 all examples I've seen seem to be using class tokens. For example:

```
class Car {}

var injector = ResolveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  { provide: Car, useClass: Car },
             ^^^
  { provide: Engine, useClass: Engine }
]);
```

I'm wondering what are the valid token types? Are they can based on TypeScript data types or JavaScript datatypes? When resolving dependencies, angular [uses metadata](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html). So is valid token types are those that are valid inside metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- TypeScript classes, (but not interfaces)
- strings
- [OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html)
- object instances (see also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13944)

Comment: thanks, what about `Object` token from the docs _Using an OpaqueToken is preferable to using an `Object` as tokens because it provides better error messages._?

Comment: Sorry, can't make any sense of this sentence. The sentence before says "`OpaqueToken` is preferable to using strings". This makes sense, because `OpaqueToken` can point to the source where it's declared and wrong imports will cause errors. Strings are duplicated if not a global constant is used and when the string is changed in one place, it might be forgotten on others.

Comment: It seems they [added support for Symbol](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13701) as tokens, right?

Comment: Just a pull request, not yet merged or even released.

Comment: right, you added `objects` - what is that? a POJO reference as a token?

Comment: I'm thinking that Symbol once released will probably replace OpaqueToken. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, no idea. I don't use either that much that it actually matters to me ;-)

Comment: I see, I'll try asking on github